# How to display formatted HTML in GridField DataColumn in Silverstripe 4

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

We have an object which has two fields - one is `Text`, the other is `HTMLText`:

```
private static $db = [
    'Question' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'Answer' => 'HTMLText'
];
```

We are referencing this object in a `Gridfield` using `DataColumns`:

```
$questionsGrid = GridField::create(
  'Questions', 'Questions', 
  $this->Questions(), 
  GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()
);

$dataColumns = $questionsGrid->
  getConfig()->getComponentByType(GridFieldDataColumns::class);

$dataColumns->setDisplayFields([
        'Question' => 'Question',
        'Answer' => 'Answer'
    ]);
    $dataColumns->setFieldCasting([
        'Question' => 'Text',
        'Answer' => 'HTMLText'
    ]);
```

Yet the `Answer` column is displayed as raw HTML - with visible tags & no formatting.

> `<p>The answer to life the universe & everything is 42.</p><p>A second paragraph for good measure.</p>`

How do we display the `Answer` column as formatted HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `'HTMLFragment->RAW'` for that column

```
$dataColumns->setFieldCasting([
    'Question' => 'Text',
    'Answer' => 'HTMLFragment->RAW'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a method on a `DataObject` subclass being rendered as a row in a GridField to achieve the same thing, you simply cast it as `HTMLText`:

```
    /**
     * @return HTMLText
     */
    public function ImageNice(): \HTMLText
    {
        $image = '<img src="/path/to/foo.png" />';
        return \DBField::create_field(\HTMLText::class, $image);
    }
```